# getting 303 See other when trying to send data from one Action to another Action in playframework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am trying to send JSON data from `ActionA` to `ActionB` using PlayFramework flashing. Here is the code:

#### Routes:

```
POST   /ActionA    controllers.InstitutionController.ActionA
POST   /ActionB    controllers.GalleryController.ActionB
```

#### Actions:

```
class InstitutionController extends Controller {
   def ActionA = Action { implicit request =>
    var jsonRequest = request.body.asJson.get
    val uuid = (jsonRequest \ "uuid").as[String]
    log.info("in ActionA" + uuid)
    Redirect("/ActionB").flashing("uuid" -> uuid)
  }
}

class GalleryController extends Controller {
 def ActionB = Action { implicit request =>
    val uuid = request.flash.get("uuid")
    log.info("in ActionB " + uuid)
      Ok("i am ActionB with id {}"+uuid)
  }
}
```

Here is the `curl` file:

```
contentType="Content-type: application/json";

data='{  "uuid" : "123" }';
echo "    "
echo "------------------   Sending Data   ------------------"
echo "    "
echo "Content-Type : " $contentType
echo "Data : " $data


echo "    "
echo "------------------     Response     ------------------" 
echo "    "
echo "    "
```

And the `curl` command:

```
curl --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json"  --data "$data" http://localhost:9000/ActionA
```

The expected response is "i am ActionB with id 123" but I am getting this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: /ActionB
Date: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 08:59:29 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Why I am getting this response? Why `ActionB` is not getting called?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong here. Using `Redirect` in PlayFramework results to a *303* http code.

You have to tell curl to follow HTTP redirects, with `-L` option :

```
curl -L --include --request POST --header "Content-type: application/json"  --data "$data" http://localhost:9000/ActionA
```

Comment: after trying this i am getting following exception  16:05:48.079 142383 [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] BodyParsers DEBUG - Invalid Json
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: [B@58728a2; line: 1, column: 1]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3609) ~[jackson-databind-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]

Comment: this happens Only when  i add -L to the curl file